# Selecting element after 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to select multiple elements at once for a function. I've got

jQuery

```
$('[class^="shapeLeft"]').click(function(){
  var $parent = $(this).parent()
  var $both   = $(this, 'this + div[class^="shapeRight"]')
  $both.css({'height': parent.height() + 20})
})
```

HTML

```
<div class="shapeLeftDiamond"></div>
<div class="shapeRightDiamond"></div>
```

The part where I say `$(this, 'this + div[class^="shapeRight"]')` doesn't seem to work.
The clicked element does get its height changed, but its direct neighbor with a class starting with `shapeRight` doesn't.

How do I select the clicked element **and** its `shapeRight` sibling at once?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use `next()`?

Comment: can you use children() ?

Comment: I want to write something that is going to select a whole lot of elements. Using next(), I would neet to write that a lot of times, which is unpractical

Comment: Deleting your previous question because you did not like the responses you were getting, and then asking basically the same thing again without any further explanation as to why you (supposedly) can’t use `.next` … now that deserves a downvote.

Comment: @CBroe I changed the question and added a Fiddle

Comment: _“I changed the question”_ – and yet, you added no more actual _useful_ information as to what you actually want to achieve. _“I need to select multiple elements at once”_ – _what_ “multiple elements”, what do you need to select them _for_, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use `.next()` if it is the exact following node

```
var thisShape = $(this).next().addBack();
```

or use `.siblings()` if they share the same parent but might have other elements in the DOM between them

```
var thisShape = $(this).siblings('[class^="shapeRight"]').addBack();
```

In both cases you alse need to add the `.addBack()` at the end, to include the current element in the selection (*the `this` in your case*)

Demo at https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/qukkwvL1/3/

Comment: Looking back at this horribly received first question, I now realize that your answer was the first to correctly do what I tried to achieve, so I've now accepted it :)

Answer (score 3):

Starting with `this`, here's how to find **all** siblings matching a selector:

```
var allSiblings = $(this).siblings("the-selector-here");
```

Here's how to find all **following** siblings:

```
var allSiblings = $(this).nextAll("the-selector-here");
```

Here's how to find **one** following sibling that may not be adjacent:

```
var allSiblings = $(this).nextAll("the-selector-here").first();
```

More in [the API documentation](http://api.jquery.com).

From your fiddle, I don't know which of those you want, but in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29215600/selecting-element-after-this#comment46640642_29215600) you said:

> I want to write something that is going to select a whole lot of elements.

...which makes me think you want `nextAll` (without `first`). Then there's [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29215600/selecting-element-after-this/29215656?noredirect=1#comment46640824_29215656):

> I need to select the element after this AND this at the same time

...which means you also want `.add(this)`:

```js
$(".shapeLeftDiamond").click(function() {
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  var thisShape = $(this).nextAll("div[class^='shapeRight']").add(this);
  thisShape.height(parent.height() + 20);
})
```

```css
main {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #F13;
}
.shapeLeftDiamond {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #FF0;
}
.shapeRightDiamond {
  float: right;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #0FF;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="shapeLeftDiamond">Click me</div>
  <div class="shapeRightDiamond">Should also grow</div>
</main>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I need to select the element after this AND this at the same time. This only selects the element after this

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove `this` from the selector (`this` has no meaning in CSS selectors) and change the order of your parameters. The [selector string comes first](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context), followed by the context:

```
$(".shapeLeftDiamond").click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    var thisShape = $("+ div[class^='shapeRight']", this);
    thisShape.height(parent.height() + 20);
});
```

**Edit:** If you want both elements to grow, use `.add()`:

```
thisShape.add(this).height(parent.height() + 20);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qukkwvL1/4/

Comment: But now only the second element grows, and not 'this'

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
$(this, "this + div[class^='shapeRight']");
```

Means:

Look for the element `this` in the context of `this + div[class^='shapeRight']"`. where the second `this` in the string would be an element `<this/>`, not the object.

---

You want to use either `$(this).next(".shapeRightDiamond")` or `$(this).siblings(".shapeRightDiamond")` to get the element beside the one that was clicked. To link the elements to the same set, you want to use [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) or [`.addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/)

```
var elems = $(this).add( $(this).next(".shapeRightDiamond") );
```

or

```
var elems = $(this).next(".shapeRightDiamond").addBack();
```